# Allow mouse events to pass through a grid in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570144/allow-mouse-events-to-pass-through-semitransparent-popup) to solve my problem, but it wasn't work for me, because, I have two grids in my Layout and I need tha one of them get the mouse event and the other no. The first grid is like a title bar with buttons and where I can move my window. Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions?

My Xaml

```
 <UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Grid Grid.Row="0">

             ....

        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
              behaviors:PopupBehavior.IsPopupEventTransparent="True">

              .....

        </Grid>
   </Grid></UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you please show your xaml so we can help you with YOUR problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false` on a root element you cant set it to `true` on any of its children. As you can see this question never got an answer [How can you set IsHitTestVisible to True on a child of something where it's set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148286/how-can-you-set-ishittestvisible-to-true-on-a-child-of-something-where-its-set).

So you can forget to have a pass-through UserControl with HitTestVisible children.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore mouse input on any WPF UI Element, you might just set its `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`.

Example:

```
<Grid>
  <Button Click="OnButtonClick" Content="The Button" />
  <Border Background="Red" Opacity="0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</Grid>
```

The red semi-transparent border will be displayed in front of the button. Still, the button will receive click events, because the hit test is disabled for the border.

Further reading: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but I need that the mouse events to pass through my UserControl too, but just in this grid.